# Cinelli old-school road bicycle

Tags: road-bike, fork

[image]

I would like to change the front fork to my road bike, but since I do not know which specifications to follow, I prefer to ask you guys

Comment: Nice bike - what do you hope to gain by changing the front fork?

Comment: On second thoughts - that quill stem might be one of the sort known for fracturing at the bolt.  Please have a really good look at all surfaces, especially around bolt holes.

Comment: They feel and look good, but just i'll keep checking just in case

Comment: I just want to know wich fork to get from Amazon. I want to change it for aesthetic reasons, that's why i'm looking for a chromed one. What do you think about this one? https://www.amazon.com/Sunlite-Threaded-Length-Chrome-Non-Canti/dp/B000AO9NTK/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1524412973&sr=8-4&keywords=road+sunlite+fork

Comment: you will need a 1" threadded fork, for a 700c or 28" wheel size (depending on what size wheels you have in there)  and a lower-race to thread measurement that matches your current fork.  And fit brand new bearings because they're cheap.   We don't do specific product recommendations.

Comment: Your other option is to get your existing fork blasted and chromed.  As long as the lower race and threads are protected, and the fork has no cracks or damage, then this preserves the authenticity somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a 1in threaded fork. You'll also want to measure the night of the threaded tube to match it as closely as possible in length and make sure that you get one for a caliper type brake rather than post mount.

Comment: Welcome to SE - that's a good first answer.  Thank you for your contribution, and feel free to try other questions too.